# Add ellipsis only if it is longer than the specified number of characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to add an ellipsis after a description only if the description is longer than the specified number of characters?

```
<Markdown
  source={he.decode(`${props.description.substring(0,500)}...`)}
  escapeHtml={false}
/>
```

This always will add "..." after each description

Comment: Not sure of the optimal React way to do this, but CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis` does this based on container width (see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow_hover)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this. It will add ... only if the description length is greater than 500.

```
<Markdown
  source={he.decode(`${props.description.substring(0,500)}${props.description.length > 500 ? '...' : ''}`)}
  escapeHtml={false}
/>
```

Comment: Here is a working example https://codepen.io/runonce86/pen/YzPNJKW?editors=0011

Comment: The ellipsis should be a single character, … or HTML entity &hellip;.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `...` after you perform your `substring` so whether or not the string get's truncated you're concatenating the ellipses.

To get passed this, you can write a quick function that returns either the string or a truncated version depending on character length. I wrote it with a limit of 5 chars for demonstrative purposes but just replace the 15's with 500.

```
<Markdown
  source={he.decode(()=>{this.checkChars(props.description)}}
  escapeHtml={false}
/>
```

```js
checkChars = (str) => {
  var max = 15
  //replace 15 with 500
  return str.length > max ? str.substring(0, max) + '...' : str
}

console.log(checkChars("HELLO MY NAME IS BUDDY"))
```